# How can I extract the 11th and 12th characters of a grep match in Bash?

Tags: bash, grep, cut

I have a text file called temp.txt that consists of 3 serial numbers.

```
AB400-251429-0014
AA200-251429-0028
AD200-251430-0046
```

The 11th and 12th characters in the serial number correspond to the week. I want to extract this number for each unit and do something with it (but for this example just echo it). I have the following code:

```
while read line; do
   week=` grep A[ABD][42]00 $line | cut -c11-12 `
   echo $week
done < temp.txt
```

Looks like it's not working as cut is expecting a filename called the serial number in each case. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with `cut` but with `grep` which expects a filename, but gets the line contents. Also, the expression doesn't match the IDs: they don't start with S followed by A, B, or D.

You can process lines in bash without starting a subshell:

```
while read line ; do
    echo 11th and 12th characters are: "${line:10:2}".
done < temp.txt
```

Your original approach is still possible:

```
week=$( echo "$line" | grep 'S[ABD][42]00' | cut -c11-12 )
```

Note that for non matching lines, $week would be empty.

Comment: Your grep will match none of the OP's sample lines. Nothing in his corpus starts with S.

Comment: @CodeGnome His answer indicates that he knows that and he is clearly using the OP's broken grep pattern.

Comment: Please change ${line:11:2} to ${line:10:2} to make the upper portion of the answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can try also the:

```
grep -oP '.{10}\K..' filename
```

for your input prints

```
29
29
30
```

The `\K` mean, *A variable length look-behind*. With other words, the grep would look for the pattern *before* `\K` but would not include it into the result.

More precise selection of the lines:

```
grep -oP '[ABD][42]00-.{4}\K..'        # or more precise
grep -oP '^\w[ABD][42]00-.{4}\K..'     # or even more
grep -oP '^[A-Z][ABD][42]00-.{4}\K..'  # or
grep -oP '^[A-Z][ABD][42]00-\d{4}\K..' # or
```

prints like the above, but selects the *interesting* lines... :)

Comment: This will match *every* line with at least 12 characters, not just the interesting ones. Also, your use of `\K` works, but most people won't know why. pcresyntax(3) defines `\K` as "reset start of match."

Comment: @CodeGnome and what are the interesting lines? (from the OP's question: _I have a text file called temp.txt that consists of 3 serial numbers._) :) bad mood today? :)

Comment: If there are no lines to include/exclude from matching, then there's no real need to grep at all. Even though the corpus didn't include non-matching lines, the OP's regex strongly indicates that such exist. YMMV.

Comment: I like your use of `\K`, and think the answer is much improved. I'm reversing my downvote. For the benefit of future visitors, not all greps are compiled with the PCRE library. Debian has historically required a separate pcregrep package, although Ubuntu 14.04's grep accepts the -P flag just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this simple `awk`

```
awk '{print substr($0,11,2)}' text.file
29
29
30
```

---

To get it into an array that you can use later:

```
results=($(awk '{print substr($0,11,2)}' text.file))
echo "${results[@]}"
29 29 30
```

Answer (score -1):

### TL;DR

Looping with Bash is pretty inefficient, especially when reading a file a line at a time. You can get what you want faster and more effectively by using grep to cut only the interesting lines, or by using awk to avoid having to call cut in a separate pipelined process.

### GNU Grep and Cut Solution

```
$ grep '[[:alpha:]][ABD][42]' temp.txt | cut -c11,12
29
29
30
```

### Awk Solutions

```
# As far as I know, this will work on most awks. If you find an exception,
# please post a constructive comment!
$ awk -v NF=1 -v FPAT=. '/[[:alpha:]][ABD][42]00/ { print $11 $12 }' temp.txt
29
29
30

# A more elegant solution as noted by @rici that works with GNU awk,
# and possibly others.
$ gawk -v FS= '/[[:alpha:]][ABD][42]00/ { print $11 $12 }' temp.txt
29
29
30
```

### Store the Results in a Bash Array

Either way, you can store the results of your match in an Bash array to use later. For example:

```
$ results=(`grep '[[:alpha:]][ABD][42]00' temp.txt | cut -c11,12`)
$ echo "${results[@]}"
29 29 30
```

Comment: In GNU awk, the standard way to split records into individual characters is to set `FS` to the empty string, rather than using `FPAT`. The `-v FS=` solution works with most other awks, as well. (As far as I know, the only modern awk which doesn't allow it is GNU awk invoked with the `--posix` command-line option.)

Comment: @novacik With a much larger corpus it might matter, but not for the sample as posted. Benchmark it yourself, then use the 2 milliseconds you've saved wisely and well to cure world hunger or bring about universal peace in our lifetimes.

Comment: As far as I know the `FPAT` is a `gnu awk` extension, so the first one should be marked as `gawk`.  You should also get rid of old and outdated back tics and use parentheses instead. `results=($(code))`